# Search from JSON Server using jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have a search form that search a JSON mock database (json-server) for users according to category but some reason after checking almost all examples on SO and google as a whole, my code doesn't seen to work. Below is the code

```
 $("#searchBar").on("keyup", function () {
    $('.searchBar').animate({ top: "0" }, 500).animate({ left: "0" }, 500).animate({ width: "100%" }, 500);
    $('.resultArea').fadeIn();
    var query = $("#searchBar").val();
    var expression = new RegExp(query, "i");
    $.getJSON("db.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            if (value.category.query(expression) != -1 || value.username.query(expression) != -1) {
                $(".resultArea").append('<p>' + value.username + '</p>')
                alert(value.username);
            }

        });
    });
});
```

**The html**

```
<div class="searchBar">
        <input type="search" name="searchBar" id="searchBar" placeholder="Try a category 'Computer Programming'">
        <label for="submitSearch"><i class="mdi mdi-magnify"></i></label>
        <input type="submit" name="submitSearch" id="submitSearch" value="">
    </div>
```

When i try to use this, i get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
```

Please what could be the issue

Comment: value.category is undefined (or perhaps value.username).  What does your response data look like?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that value.category and/or value.username are undefined.

You need to check the data retrieved by your server because it seems to be different to the data you excepted to have. You can inspect the data being sent by the server with your browser's DevTools or by doing a simple console.log(data).